# Prolog predicate calling

Tags: prolog, dcg

In the following tutorial: http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/7_3.html

There is the part:

```
test_parser :- repeat,
               write('?? '), 
               read_line(X),
               ( c(F,X,[])   | q(F,X,[])  ),
               nl, write(X), nl, write(F), nl, fail.
```

Now I'm extremely confused about the c(F,X,[]) and q(F,X,[]) part because it doesn't seem to match any thing that I have seen, c only takes one parameter from what I can tell and these parameters don't seem to make sense for q. Please help me understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is defined with `-->`, which actually adds two hidden arguments to it. The first of these is a list to be parsed by the grammar rule; the second is "what's left" after the parse. `c(F,X,[])` calls `c` on the list `X` to obtain a result `F`, expecting `[]` to be left, i.e. the parser should consume the entire list `X`.

Answer (score 6):

**c//1** and  **q//1** are entry points (aka top level production) of the Definite Clauses Grammar defined below, where you find

```
c(F) --> ....
q(F) --> ....
```

This style of 'call' on a DCG entry point is discouraged, usually is better to invoke the **phrase(Grammar, TextToAnalyze, TextAfterAnalysis)**, in this case `phrase((c(F) ; q(F)), "some text", "")...`

The `-->` operator is usually rewritten adding 2 arguments, that are cause of your concern.

*EDIT*

I.e.
`c(L) --> lead_in,arrange(L),end.`

is rewritten to

`c(L,X,Y) :- lead_in(X,X1),arrange(L,X1,X2),end(X2,Y).`

Comment: That didn't exactly help me understand the point of having q(F,X,[]). Is there any other way you can try to explain what you are trying to say?